# Guake character problems in ssh with zsh

Tags: command-line, ssh, zsh, prompt, guake

I am using Guake to SSH into a server. My terminal is using zsh and Oh My Zsh and works fine. The server I ssh into also using zsh with the exact same settings and theme. However, whenever I toggle out of Guake and back into it, strange characters appear. This only happens when I am using ssh to the other server, never on the local prompt.

[image]

When I start typing, it fixes itself and goes back to normal. It only occurs when I re-toggle Guake. This doesn't happen in the Gnome Terminal.

[image]

Also, if I switch the ssh server back to Bash, the problem goes away.

After testing on my own a bit longer. I realized this issue only occurs if I have Guake running in fullscreen, which is normally how I have it setup.

Comment: This seems to be related to the [bug 2477](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2477). What do you see in the output of `stty` in both cases?

Comment: Sorry it took so long, here is the stty: 
```speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
-brkint ixany```

Comment: Edit the question with the details.